# Can't restart apache via ssh

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh, apache2

Connecting via ssh (with Mobaxterm or PuTTY) to container Docker, on which is installed Ubuntu. User is sudoer (not root).

ssh version installed in the container

```
# ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

This command

```
# sudo service apache2 restart
```

return

```
* Restarting web server apache2
```

then remains stuck until <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or timeout. Apache is not restarted. No lines in apache error log.

Opening the console of the container via Portainer interface (user is root in this case), and restarting apache properly works.

```
# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2

[ OK ]
```

What I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Commands like `service` don't usually work in Docker, nor do you usually get an interactive shell in a container (they very rarely run ssh daemons).  If you need to restart the main container process, delete and recreate the container.

Comment: Commands depends on the opertaing system you install in the container. I don't need to restart the main container process, i need to restart apache service of the container via ssh as I do in the console. And yes, ssh daemon is running as can successfully connect both with PuTTY and Mobaxterm

Comment: Just curious why are you restarting this service from container? Normally if the service running in docker container is stopped we spin up another container.

Comment: Service is not stopped. I just have to restart apache in the container to apply some configurations.